# Google Apps Script- TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined at sendFormByEmail

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

As of two days ago a script that was embedded in a google spreadsheet that ran without fail for years has suddenly started failing with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
> at sendFormByEmail(Code:15:62)

The script itself is:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e){
 var email = "myLNCF.testemail@gmail.com";
 var subject = "Employee Call Out: \n"  + e.namedValues["Employee's First and Last Name"] + "\nDept: \n" + e.namedValues["Employee's Department"];
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var message = "";
  for(var i in headers)
    message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 
}
```

Any help is appreciated, as I am a very novice coder.

Comment: Try to change this `var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`  ---> `var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('nameOfTheSheet')` And define the sheetname where you store the form values

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendFormByEmail(e){
 var email = "myLNCF.testemail@gmail.com";
 var subject = "Employee Call Out: \n"  + e.namedValues["Employee's First and Last Name"] + "\nDept: \n" + e.namedValues["Employee's Department"];
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
  var message = "";
  for(var i in headers)
    message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]][0] + "\n\n";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 
}
```

If you have changed the questions in the form that could also change which e.namedValues you want